# Terminal tab opens with error, says module.js is throwing error

Tags: javascript, terminal, npm, iterm2

Whenever I open a new terminal or terminal tab (via Mac's Terminal or iTerm2) I encounter with an error at the top saying `Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nixar/compiled-commands/uniq.js'`. The complete error is below.

```
Last login: Sat Aug 20 15:01:02 on ttys001
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nixar/compiled-commands/uniq.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at loadString (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nixar/node_modules/xonom/index.js:44:7)
    at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nixar/node_modules/xonom/index.js:56:14)
    at Object.x$.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nixar/node_modules/xonom/index.js:109:5)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nixar/nixar.js:214:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nixar/refs/uniq:2:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
```

How can I get rid of this behavior?

Comment: what type of shell your are using ? this error maybe cause by something in your ```.bashrc``` or ```.zshrc```.

Comment: I am using `bash`. I did not intentionally update my `.bashrc`. Latest I remember is updating my globally installed node packages.

Comment: you're right, the error maybe caused one of your npm package, but it maybe invoked from ```.bashrc``` or other files. you can check it out by running ```source .bashrc``` or ```source .bash_profile```, if the error reappears, you can follow the clue.